# I am setting up PayPal on a website and am using liquid to pull the cart value into JS

Tags: javascript, html, liquid

I am setting up Paypal on a website and am using liquid to pull the cart value into the Paypal JS.

I have achieved this with the following code:

```
{% capture paypal_price %}
  {%- include 'ecommerce/price_total', format_type: 'formatted' -%}
{% endcapture %}
```

and

```
value: "{{ paypal_price | remove:'£' }}"
```

Functionally it pull through the correct price but as you can see from the image below and error occurs as it pushes it down onto a new line.

[Liquid Issue in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlWrU.png)

Is this a known issue and does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

The following amendment to the Liquid fixed it :)

```
{{ paypal_price | remove:'£' | strip_newlines }}
```